# adding and removing canvas class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I went through many links to get the answer to my problem, however, couldn't find any so decided to ask it.

I am using canvas html element to show active slide. when the next button is clicked, active canvas element border color should become normal and next canvas element border color should change to identify active. But its not working.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="slider-nav">
    <a href="#" class="arrow-prev"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-prev.png" /></a>
    <ul class="slider-dots">
        <li><canvas class="dot active-dot" width="50" height="10"></canvas></li>
        <li><canvas class="dot" width="50" height="10"></canvas></li>
        <li><canvas class="dot" width="50" height="10"></canvas></li>
        <li><canvas class="dot" width="50" height="10"></canvas></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="arrow-next"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-next.png" /></a>
</div>
```

This is the css

```
canvas {
    border:2px solid deepskyblue;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

canvas.active-dot {
    border:2px solid green;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

This is the script

```
var main = function() {
    $('.arrow-next').click(function() {
        /*var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';*/
        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var nextDot = currentDot.next();

        if(nextDot.length === 0) {
            nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        }
        $('active-dot').removeClass('active-dot');
        /*currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        nextDot.addClass('active-dot');*/
        $(this).next().addClass('active-dot');
    });

    $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {

        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

        if(prevDot.length === 0) {
            prevDot = $('.dot').last();
        }
        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
    });    
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: jquery syntax error is coming

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ea7fpdc0/1/ try it

Answer (score 0):

You have `canvas` elements in `li` so you need write `currentDot.parent().next().find('.dot');` instead of `currentDot.next()`
The same goes for the `.prev()`

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfect :). Can you identify why it didn't worked with next. The next was working perfect when there was no canvas

Answer (score 0):

try the new code

```
   $('.arrow-next').click(function() {
       var pos = $(".dot").index($('.active-dot'));
       $(".dot").removeClass("active-dot");
       $(".dot").eq(pos+1).addClass("active-dot");
       if(!$(".dot").hasClass("active-dot")){
          $(".dot").eq(0).addClass("active-dot");
       }
 });


    $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {

       var pos = $(".dot").index($('.active-dot'));
       $(".dot").removeClass("active-dot");
       $(".dot").eq(pos-1).addClass("active-dot");
    });
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ea7fpdc0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to traverse the parent and the next element for the code to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.arrow-next').click(function() {

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot').parent();
    var nextDot = currentDot.next().children('canvas');

    if (nextDot.length === 0) {
      nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    }
    $('canvas.active-dot').removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
  });

  $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot').parent();
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev().children('canvas');

    if (prevDot.length === 0) {
      prevDot = $('.dot').last();
    }
    $('canvas.active-dot').removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
  });
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid deepskyblue;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
canvas.active-dot {
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-nav">
  <a href="#" class="arrow-prev">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-prev.png" />
  </a>
  <ul class="slider-dots">
    <li>
      <canvas class="dot active-dot" width="50" height="10"></canvas>
    </li>
    <li>
      <canvas class="dot" width="50" height="10"></canvas>
    </li>
    <li>
      <canvas class="dot" width="50" height="10"></canvas>
    </li>
    <li>
      <canvas class="dot" width="50" height="10"></canvas>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="arrow-next">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-next.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```